# Delegate without performSegue not getting called Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

My protocol (where "VehicleRegVCs" is enum):

```
protocol VehicleRegVCDelegate: class {
        func presentedVC(_ currentVC: VehicleRegVCs)
    }
```

My Buyer Class:

```
class BuyerOwnerInfoViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: VehicleRegVCDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate?.presentedVC(.buyerOwnerInfo)
    }
}
```

My Main class (where delegate function "func presentedVC" at the bottom not getting called):

```
class VehicleRegContainerViewController: ICTViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        let buyerVC = getBuyerOwnerInfoVC()
        buyerVC.delegate = self
    }
}

extension VehicleRegContainerViewController: VehicleRegVCDelegate {
    func presentedVC(_ currentVC: VehicleRegVCs) {

    }
}
```

I expect "presentedVC" to get called... I made a delegate too...

and in UIViewController extension i have made this function...

```
    func getBuyerOwnerInfoVC() -> BuyerOwnerInfoViewController {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.exciseAndTaxation.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BuyerOwnerInfoViewController") as! BuyerOwnerInfoViewController
        return vc
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how `getBuyerOwnerInfoVC` is implemented and how and where you presented `BuyerOwnerInfoViewController`?

Comment: ```func getBuyerOwnerInfoVC() -> BuyerOwnerInfoViewController {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.exciseAndTaxation.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BuyerOwnerInfoViewController") as! BuyerOwnerInfoViewController
        return vc
    }

```
BuyerOwnerInfoViewController is presented successfully, because viewDidLoad is getting called...

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: actually BuyerOwnerInfoViewController is in container view...

Comment: @JawadAli you are creating a new instance of VC and assigning it the delegate. That wont work. You should assign it to your embedded controller using `prepareForSegue`

Comment: @KeshuR. i got it but BuyerOwnerInfoViewController is in ContentViewController, which shows first view controller automatically... it's happening with me...

Comment: @JawadAli check my answer

Answer (score 1):

ViewController inside containerView are connected using segue. You can use prepareForSegue method to get the controller and assign the delegate to it.

**NOTE**: Go to storyboard and click on the segue connecting the container view and the view controller, and assign it an identifier. In below example i have used "yourSegueIdentifier", replace it with your identifier.

```
class VehicleRegContainerViewController: ICTViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
         if let buyerVC = segue.destination as? BuyerOwnerInfoViewController {
             buyerVC.delegate = self
         } else {
             print("Error in segue")
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: i did same, but (segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier") is false... although i have given same segue name...

(buyerVC = segue.destination as? BuyerOwnerInfoViewController) = true

and it prints "Error in segue"

Comment: i got it... you are right, there is navigation controller before "BuyerOwnerInfoViewController"....

my next question is...
How can i get reference of VC which is next to "BuyerOwnerInfoViewController"... and there is series of 5 VC next to "BuyerOwnerInfoViewController"...


At some other place, i implemeted this via Notifications... but now i am trying to achieve current presented VC via delegates...

Comment: @JawadAli ask it as a seperate question and explain it in detail there. And accept this one if it helps.